# Reset Item Height in accordion isn't resetting properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

**Edit:**
This is solved. Turns out it had something to do with the line-height in the `css` not the `js`.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ruwjn/7/

live site:
http://imip.rvadv.com/index3.html

It doesn't seem to be doing this in  the fiddle, but it is doing it on the live site.
When I click on the accordion menu item, it opens properly. When I click on the same item a second time it should close and go back to how it looked before. However, it doesn't quite happen that way. When I click on it a second time, it closes, but it leaves extra space between the accordion menu links.

I don't know much about `js`, but I think it might have to do something with this bit:

```
$(window).bind('smartresize.accordion', function( event ) {

            // reset orinal item values
            instance._saveDimValues();

            // reset the content's height of any item that is currently opened
            instance.$el.find('li.st-open').each( function() {

                var $this   = $(this);
                $this.css( 'height', $this.data( 'originalHeight' ) + $this.find('div.st-content').outerHeight( true ) );


            });

            // scroll to current
            if( instance._isOpened() )
            instance._scroll();

        });
```

If you have to explain anything about the `js`, please put it in as simple of terms as possible. I know very very little about this.

Comment: I don't see the problem on the live site in Chrome, try setting all padding and margins to 0px - see if that helps

Comment: What browser are you using? If it's working fine for you in the jsfiddle but not on the live site, then that would point to some kind of conflict with other code on your site, possibly css.

Worked fine for me in Chrome and firefox. Let me know what browser your using and I will give it a test.

Comment: I'm looking at it in firefox, but I just checked out the live site in Chrome and I am still seeing the problem. Its particularly obvious in between the second and third links.

Comment: What version of firefox/chrome? Could you take a screen grab of how it looks for you after you close the accordion?

Comment: firefox 13 and I think whatever the latest version of Chrome is. before: http://imip.rvadv.com/images/screenshots/before.PNG  after:http://imip.rvadv.com/images/screenshots/after.png

Comment: Ok, completely different to what I'm getting. have you tried inspecting the page with firebug, or the chrome dom inspector to see what the css is before/after?

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know enough to know what I'm looking for. I only know enough to get myself in trouble! LOL

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty strange one for sure. What's happening is that the **h2** on the second list item is *just* long enough to cause a line break, that for some reason is only being calculated/shown once the accordion is closed. You can see this for yourself by shortening the text inside to just a few letters. It's also happening to the **li** below it, but you can't tell since it's the last item.

To fix this simply add this to your **h2{}** in your style sheet:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

That should do it.

Comment: That improved it, but it's still there. :-)

Comment: I can't seem to see it anymore on your live site. I measured the baseline of the third li and it looks to line up before and after now. What area is still giving you problems?

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. I magically solved that problem when I solved a different problem just a few minutes ago. Had something to do with the line-height.